# JavaScript Canvas Disappears After Changing Width

Tags: javascript, canvas

After running this code:

```
var inventoryCanvas = document.getElementById("inventoryCanvas");
inventoryCanvas.width = width2;
```

it executes properly, however the canvas disappears when I run it.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: Do you have fiddle with this?

Comment: What's the value of `width2`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to stop this as it is expected behavior, I had a similar problem and solved it by creating a hidden *buffer* canvas. Before resize you can copy your original canvas to this buffer, resize the old canvas then redraw from the buffer.

Heres a quick fiddle demonstrating it:
http://jsfiddle.net/5keo7g2r/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    buffer = document.getElementById('buffer'),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    bufferContext = buffer.getContext("2d");


bufferContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0); //Make a copy of the canvas to hidden buffer
canvas.width = 50; //Resize
context.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0); //Draw it back to canvas
```

Comment: Sounds perfect - I would appreciate that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should be able to apply this to my code.

Comment: Upvote for probably the best way to resize a canvas element and restore its original content. An alternative that doesn't require a second canvas would be to start out sizing the canvas to its maximum expected size and wrapping it in a smaller div with the div's overflow:hidden -- the div becomes a viewport into the larger canvas.